# continuous and holomorphic in every variable implies holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I'm trying to find a nice proof of the next result,

> Let $Y$ be a complex Banach space, $U \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ an open set, and $f : U \rightarrow Y$. If $f$ is continuous and $f$ is holomorphic in every variable, then $f$ is holomorphic.

I know there exists a more general result of Hartogs, but I also know it has a much more complicated proof.

I've already found this result on Dieudonné's "Treatise on analysis" and Mujica's "Complex analysis in Banach spaces", but I've found trouble understanding these texts, so I'd really appreciate any other bibliography about it.

Comment: With the continuity assumption, you can easily show that Cauchy's integral formula holds. First you do it iteratively one coordinate after the other, then the continuity makes it obvious that you can convert the iterated integral into an integral over the $n$-torus.